# My 4K TV/monitor resets to an unsupported resolution as a single monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, tv, 4k-resolution

I'm running Windows 10 version 2004 and I recently bought a 4K TV.
Things were OK until it decided (after a firmware update) to try and become a 3840x2160 @ 60hz TV (which isn't supported over the HDMI cable I'm using).
So now the TV just sits there resetting my display over and over trying to output this impossible resolution.
I've hooked a second monitor up momentarily and have managed to get the two to share the same resolution (1080p @ 60hz) but whenever I revert to solely using the 4K TV, it tries to go back to only outputting 4K.
Is there a way to modify the properties of the monitor when it is the sole screen? Without it being the sole screen?

EDIT: When duplicating everything is fine. If I duplicate and turn off the standard monitor, it's still fine. It *only* becomes an issue when I choose "show only on 1" in the display settings.
I'm outputting from a 1060ti at the moment.
The TV is a TCL 55" P715.

EDIT 2: I did it. I'm still not sure how.
I tried a new HDMI cable (one I got from the Nintendo Switch) and swapped the HDMI port I was using for the PC on the TV to the one I was using for the Switch.
The Switch has no issues using the "broken" HDMI1 port that the PC couldn't, and the TV has no problems using the HDMI2 port with the Nintendo Switch HDMI cable.
With the new port and cable I was able to activate the "show only on 1" option at 4K, and then I manually adjusted the active display resolution back down to 1920x1080@60hz (but to do this I had to set it to something else, and then set it *back* to 1920x1080@60hz before it would accept that anything had changed).
I don't know why any of that worked, but it did.
Hopefully if someone else has a similar problem this will help them.